# Set root directory of HDFS in Configuration

Tags: java, database, hadoop, hdfs

I have a dir structure:

```
/  
   DIR files
   DIR usr
```

My HDFS is available at `hdfs://db:123`, so I create configuration:

```
configuration.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://db:123");
```

Then all directories / paths are relative to the root (`/`). I created a directory `files` and that is where I want to keep all my files.

Do I have to manually append `/files/` to the beginning of each path in my code or can I create configuration:

```
configuration.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://db:123/files");
```

and no changes in the code will be necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the paths you pass are either relative to the users HDFS home directory if no leading slash is passed, or absolute if prefixed with a /.

If you look in the source for Path.makeQualified you should see a test for if the path is not absolute (this is from 1.0.3):

```
/** Returns a qualified path object. */
public Path makeQualified(FileSystem fs) {
  Path path = this;
  if (!isAbsolute()) {
    path = new Path(fs.getWorkingDirectory(), this);
  }
```

`DistributedFileSystem.getWorkingDirectory()` uses a instance variable called workingDir in response, which can be set using the `setWorkingDirectory(path)` method. If you don't set the working directory yourself, the default is the user's home directory (as can be seen in the `DistributedFileSystem.initialize(..)` method:

```
this.workingDir = getHomeDirectory();
```

And `DistributedFileSystem.getHomeDirectory()`:

```
public Path getHomeDirectory() {
  return new Path("/user/" + dfs.ugi.getShortUserName()).makeQualified(this);
}
```

It doesn't appear you can configure the working directory via a configuration property so you're going to have to call the following before you submit your job (after which all relative paths will be relative to /files):

```
FileSystem.get(configuration).setWorkingDirectory("/files");
```